# How to put a validation process before the cell get updated?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am using xamdatagrid, want to have a column to remove the record which is a checkbox.

When user click on the checkbox, there would be a pop-up asking conformation.
But if user say no, the data should not be updated...
So kind of put a logic the CellUpdating(EditModeStart/EditModeEnd)

But cant find a way to terminate the update process, please help~

Answer (score 0):

in the EditModeEnding, I can set AcceptChanges=false to terminate the update

Comment: It would be a better user experience to allow undo rather than prompting for confirmation.  For this you could use the Undo/Redo framework that Infragistics provides: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2012.2/CLR4.0/?page=Undo_Redo_Framework.html